# Pair two elements of a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have a foreach loop (look, it's below), and I'm getting a few elements. When storing this data into MySQL, I want to select to which category (labeled here 'interaction[]') each 'count[]' belongs. For example, if row 1 has a count of 97, and those happen to be "chas", I can select "cha" from my dropdown, set it's value, and enter it into the table. Looking to do this for each instance of title[].

Yes, the json part works. Yes, data is populated. Yes, I've searched. There are no errors.

Hope this makes sense, and I really can't express my gratitude enough. I hope to one day be able to not ask these stupid questions but, hey, that's a ways off. Let me know if anything else needs to be clarified.

```
    foreach ($json->report->data as $key=>$el) {
           ?> 
           <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $key; ?>" name="row[]">
            <?php
                echo "<tr><td><input name=\"title[]\" value=\"".$el->name."\" />".$el->name."</td>
                <td><input name=\"count[]\" value=\"".$el->counts[0]."\" />".$el->counts[0]."</td>
                <td>".$key."</td>
                <td><select name=\"interaction[]\"><option value=\"blah\">blah</option><option value=\"ha\">ha</option><option value=\"cha\">cha</option></select></td></tr>";
        }
```

Comment: So what part isn't working or what part don't you understand?

Comment: Hey @Tom, I don't understand how to say "if interaction[] equals cha, I want you to store the corresponding value from count[] into the database" in php. If the next row is a blah, I want to take that corresponding value and store it separately. Similarly, if a row isn't needed, I don't want to worry about storing it.

Comment: As in after the POST takes effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match up the interaction value to the count value after a POST has been made, you can loop through the interactions array and match the count array.

```
foreach ($_POST['interaction'] as $key => $value) {
    $insertText = $value;
    $insertCount = $_POST['count'][$key];
}
```

Then do the insert however your database is set up. Preferably with PDO or MySQLi.

Example (not tested):

```
<?php
    $sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (interaction, count) VALUES ";

    $data = array();
    $x = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['interaction'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($x > 0) $sql .= ", ";
        $sql .= "(:interaction_{$x}, :count_{$x})";
        $data['interaction_' . $x] = $value;
        $data['count_' . $x] = $_POST['count'][$key];
    }
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute($data);
```

Comment: That did it Tom! Thanks a bunch, I really appreciate it.